# Does setBalance always overwrite?

Tags: parachain, storage, kusama, kabocha

We are uploading balances to a parachain. And there are some errors, so we would like to overwrite all ~20k balances. Is setBalance safe enough to overwrite, or is there a cleaner way such as reaping all the balances in question, and then setBalance thereafter?

Secondly, does setBalance to zero remove the leaves from the trie, or does 0.000 remain in the trie?

Comment: Of course balances that are zero will be reaped, if the chain has reaping set up.

Comment: What are you doing exactly? What errors do you get? This is not enough info to really help you. The cleanest solution is a storage migration since its atomic and cannot be interfered with. Otherwise a batch call could work, but maybe not with 20k at once.

Comment: batch call wont do it, were uploading balances to an already launched chain, we created a custom scheduler to upload 20k balance distribution, which unvests at a relayblocknumber which can be changed by root. 

Just checking if theres ever been weird behaviour that setBalance didnt overwrite. But i think its all good. thanks